# Is "make the largest possible X but not too large" grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality

Someone claimed this sentence is using incorrect grammar:

> Make the largest possible X but not too large.

Context: imagine you have an API that tells you the largest supported size. You want to test whether that size is actually supported, but if the API reports a size larger than the amount of memory you have that would be "too large".

Is this incorrect English usage?

Update:

I'm only asking about the grammar. I'm not looking for suggestions on better ways to phrase things. Remember that the sentence has a context. If someone says "Go to the jewelry store and buy me the most expensive necklace but not too expensive", whether that is correct grammar is a valid question by itself.

The person being asked to go might then ask "How expensive is too expensive?" but whether or not that clarifying question exists is independent from whether or not the first sentence is grammatical or ungrammatical.

Comment: It is grammatically correct, but contradictory.

Comment: Can you explain more about what is supposed to be the problem with it? I wonder how picky we're supposed to be. Even eliminating the logic problem, "Make a very big house but not too big", well, lacks a comma for starters. And *maybe* we could get picky about some parallelism in the adjectivals... but I'm not sure you're asking along those lines. You'll get better answers if you clarify.

Comment: It should be made clear what counts as "too large" instead, e.g., "Make the largest possible X without ..."

Comment: How can it be made larger than possible? That would be impossible.

Comment: "You drew his hands impossibly large" i.e., unrealistically large.

Comment: The largest X that is possible without...

Comment: @YosefBaskin Isn't that just Make X with value (Y - some minimum)?

Comment: *Make the largest possible X without exceeding memory. / Memory exceeded.*

Comment: In a programming context I'd say "Maximum allowable value of X, <value>"

Comment: It's unacceptable, but not on grammatical grounds. 'Someone claimed this sentence is using incorrect grammar', on the other hand ....

Comment: The coordinating conjunction "but" should connect two conjuncts. The second appears to be an adjective phrase ("not too large").* For the conjuncts to be parallel, the first should also be an adjective phrase. However, "X" (which I assume is a noun) appears to head that phrase, making it a nominal and not an adjective. Therefore, there seems to be a lack of parallelism. // *Arguably it could be an adverb phrase, but that wouldn't affect my point.

Comment: Seems like some people are answering the question "What is a better way to phrase this sentence" and while I really appreciate the suggestions, that's not the question that was asked. 

Comment: In terms of technical correctness I guess "Make X as large as possible but not too large" would be better.  (And then taking into account the *meaning*, "Make X very large, but not too large," would be even better.)

Answer (score 1):

Comprehensiblity, grammaticality and internal consistency etc are different things that are sometimes lazily described simply as 'grammar'. Your follow-up question about "English usage" is much broader, but I will ignore that breadth here since the question title and the update posted in the question restrict your scope of interest for this question to grammar.

We can consider the sentence to be of the form "Make it X but not Y". This is grammatical.

The structure of your quote is the same as that of one considered by [Quote Investigator](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2011/05/13/einstein-simple/). Quote Investigator cites a New York Times article by Roger Sessions that includes the following paraphrase of a famous Einstein quote: "... everything should be made as simple as possible, but not simpler".

Answer (score 0):

The construct refers to “the least of {A and B}”. “The least of {A (the most expensive of the available necklaces) and B (the necklace that can be afforded)}”. “The least of {A (the requested memory) and B (the available memory)}”.

Is “A but B” an acceptable alternative? We now have “The most {A(expensive) but B(affordable)} necklace}. The most {A(requested) but B(available)} memory”}.

Grammar serves meaning. Both conjunctions, when understood in these ways, are acceptable and lead to the same meaning. “And” produces a plain statement, whereas “but” introduces a note of contrast that seems to reflect the way that our minds often work,